# Onclick opens video in fullscreen

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make the video element when it clicked will be opened in full screen mode. As there is no way to do this directly with video tag, using Full Screen Api

```
var elem = document.getElementById("myvideo");
if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
  elem.requestFullscreen();
} else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
  elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
} else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
  elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
} else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { 
  elem.msRequestFullscreen();
}
```

But i am unaware how to do this in react, as its mentioned that instead of document.getElementById, we should use useRef.

Here is my below snippet, how to achieve this.

```
import { useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const vidRef = useRef(null);

  return (
    <video width="350" height="200" controls ref={vidRef}>
      <source
        src={"http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.ogv"}
        type="video/mp4"
      />
    </video>
  );
}
```

So that when the user clicks on it should open in full screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you almost found the solution yourself:

```
import { useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const vidRef = useRef(null);

  const handlePlay = () => {
      const elem = vidRef.current
      if(elem){ //checking if ref was initiated
        if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
          elem.requestFullscreen();
        } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Safari */
          elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE11 */
          elem.msRequestFullscreen();
        }
      }
  }

  return (
    <video width="350" height="200" controls ref={vidRef}>
      <source
        src={"http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.ogv"}
        type="video/mp4"
        onPlay={handlePlay}
      />
    </video>
  );
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but not working its not opening in full screen mode when click on play in video controls

Comment: then replace onClick with onPlay

Comment: okay, cool. One doubt when i use map and return multiple videos how could i use the ref ? because if i understand correctly ref is identifying element for each video tag isn't so ?

Comment: I suggest to create an extra component for this and then use this component in the map. Each component will have own ref:
`
const VideoFullScreen: React.FC = ({src}) {
    const vidRef = ...
    const handleClick = ...
    ...
    <video src={src} ... >
}

...

export default function App() {
  return videos.map(v => <VideoFullScreen src="v"/>)
}
`

Comment: Yep i have done the same, thanks. Didn't updated :) sorry

Comment: Can you update to onPlay so i could accept and for future ref it will be helpful

Comment: @John Thomas, I've updated my answer as you asked

Comment: @ devrnd, just one quick question, is there reference, that same like a feature for image. So what i am thinking is on click of image it should go to full screen and clicking on close icon it should come back is there a way

Comment: in that case i would rather use a combination of `useState` and css class: `const [active, toggleAcctive]=useState(false) .... <img className={`${active?"fullscreen":""}`} onClick={()=>toggleActive(true)} />

Comment: is there codesandbox you have so i can refer the same, it will be helpful

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-darkness-zsw3z?file=/src/ImageViewer/ImageViewer.tsx

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but i think this will work:

```
import { useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
        
const vidRef = useRef(null);

const requestFullScreen = (elem) =>{
if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
  elem.requestFullscreen();
} else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
  elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
} else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
  elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
} else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { 
  elem.msRequestFullscreen();
}
}
const openFullScreen = ()=>{
    requestFullScreen(vidRef.current)
}
return (
    <video width="350" height="200" controls ref={vidRef} onClick={openFullScreen}>
          <source
            src={"http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.ogv"}
            type="video/mp4"
          />
        </video>
      );
}
```

Comment: Nope didn't worked, when clicking on play its not opening in full screen